# Parse HTML table to Python list?

Tags: python, html

I'd like to take an HTML table and parse through it to get a list of dictionaries. Each list element would be a dictionary corresponding to a row in the table.

If, for example, I had an HTML table with three columns (marked by header tags), "Event", "Start Date", and "End Date" and that table had 5 entries, I would like to parse through that table to get back a list of length 5 where each element is a dictionary with keys "Event", "Start Date", and "End Date".

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You should use some HTML parsing library like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/):

```
from lxml import etree
s = """<table>
  <tr><th>Event</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
  <tr><td>g</td><td>h</td><td>i</td></tr>
</table>
"""
table = etree.HTML(s).find("body/table")
rows = iter(table)
headers = [col.text for col in next(rows)]
for row in rows:
    values = [col.text for col in row]
    print dict(zip(headers, values))
```

prints

```
{'End Date': 'c', 'Start Date': 'b', 'Event': 'a'}
{'End Date': 'f', 'Start Date': 'e', 'Event': 'd'}
{'End Date': 'i', 'Start Date': 'h', 'Event': 'g'}
```

Comment: My table has a varying number of rows. How can I make it work if this is the case? Thanks for the response, btw.

Comment: @Andrew: The above code works for any number of rows and any number of columns, as long as every row has the same number of columns.

Comment: I'd suggest `HTMLParser`/`html.parser`, but this solution is much better in this case.

Comment: This was a useful pointer for additional research. I actually have some broken HTML to parse, so some other answers involving lxml.html also proved useful.

Comment: it fails if html contains unquoted attrs like "<table align=center" with lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: AttValue: " or ' expected

Comment: @Maxdestroyer Looking at this again, you should probably user `etree.HTML`, not `etree.XML` to get a more relaxed syntax.

Comment: @Maxdestroyer Edited my answer.

Comment: also, <tbody> and <thead> don't work. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49286753/8929814

Answer (score 75):

Hands down the easiest way to parse a HTML table is to use [pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) - it accepts both URLs and HTML.

```
import pandas as pd
url = r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
tables = pd.read_html(url) # Returns list of all tables on page
sp500_table = tables[0] # Select table of interest
```

As of pandas version 1.5.0, `read_html()` can preserve hyperlinks with the `extract_links` argument. Table elements will be tuples.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This was very quick and easy.

Comment: Not a good way for tables containing `rowspan` and `colspan`!

Comment: @JohnStrood Looking forward to reading your answer on how to handle `rowspan` and `colspan` 

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Ah! I used `bs4` to build an element tree, and traversed through the elements to break row-spanned column-spanned cells into constituent cells.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen There are already answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39336433/5337834 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980393/5337834. If you're still unsatisfied, I'll write my own answer!

Comment: @zelusp I just learned, that Pandas is *extremely* slow, if your html has 100+ tables and you just want a single table with a specific `id`. Beautifulsoup is much faster in this case.

Comment: This method is really simple and also works for small table findings, loved it! Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

Sven Marnach [excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325216/parse-html-table-to-python-list/6325277#6325277) is directly translatable into [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which is part of recent Python distributions:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

s = """<table>
  <tr><th>Event</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
  <tr><td>g</td><td>h</td><td>i</td></tr>
</table>
"""

table = ET.XML(s)
rows = iter(table)
headers = [col.text for col in next(rows)]
for row in rows:
    values = [col.text for col in row]
    print(dict(zip(headers, values)))
```

same output as Sven Marnach's answer...

Comment: +1 because it allows using cElementTree instead of ElementTree which is considerably faster than lxml if large number of tables are involved

Comment: I have a web page saved from wikipedia. How can I specify to ET which table to parse and fetch data ? Is it possible by table name or table id ?

Comment: also, <tbody> and <thead> don't work. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49286753/8929814

Answer (score 21):

If the HTML is **not** XML you can't do it with *etree*. But even then, you don't have to use an external library for parsing a HTML table. In python 3 you can reach your goal with `HTMLParser` from `html.parser`. I've the code of the simple derived HTMLParser class [here in a github repo](https://github.com/schmijos/html-table-parser-python3/blob/master/html_table_parser/parser.py).

You can use that class (here named `HTMLTableParser`) the following way:

```
import urllib.request
from html_table_parser import HTMLTableParser

target = 'http://www.twitter.com'

# get website content
req = urllib.request.Request(url=target)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
xhtml = f.read().decode('utf-8')

# instantiate the parser and feed it
p = HTMLTableParser()
p.feed(xhtml)
print(p.tables)
```

The output of this is a list of 2D-lists representing tables. It looks maybe like this:

```
[[['   ', ' Anmelden ']],
 [['Land', 'Code', 'Für Kunden von'],
  ['Vereinigte Staaten', '40404', '(beliebig)'],
  ['Kanada', '21212', '(beliebig)'],
  ...
  ['3424486444', 'Vodafone'],
  ['  Zeige SMS-Kurzwahlen für andere Länder ']]]
```

Comment: Awesome parser !!

Comment: neat indeed. It will break if some td have a colspan though

Comment: @mr.bjerre PR welcome ;-)