# Confused on this regular expression pattern in Python

Tags: python, html, regex

I wanna find 6 digit in my webpage:

`<td style="width:40px;">705214</td>`

My code is:

```
s = f.read()
m = re.search(r'\A>\d{6}\Z<', s)
l = m.group(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to find 6 digits in between a `>` and `<` symbol, use the following regex:

```
import re
s = '<td style="width:40px;">705214</td>'
m = re.search(r'>(\d{6})<', s)
l = m.groups()[0]
```

Note the use of parentheses `(` and `)` to denote a capturing group.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do this for multiple strings (same as above) it means if I have multiple 6 digit numbers , how can I pick them up ?

Comment: Technically a separate question, but try this: m = re.findall(r'>(\d{6})<', s + s + s) ... m is then a list of matches.

Comment: @PaulKarlin's answer is quite right, though note that the `s + s + s` is only for the test case (don't do that with your actual html)

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's a bit harder to demonstrate a working example in comments, which is why I subsequently edited my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
m = re.search(r'>(\d{6})<', s)
l = m.group(1)
```

The ( ) around `\d{6}` indicate a subgroup of the result.

If you want to find multiple instances of 6-digit substrings between `>` and `<` then try this:

```
s = '<tag1>111111</tag1> <tag2>222222</tag2>'
m = re.findall(r'>(\d{6})<', s)
```

In this case, `m` will be `['111111','222222']`.

Comment: Do you get an error, or no match?  Is your page guaranteed to have a 6-digit string inside a tag like the example in your question?

Comment: No problem.  I do recommend adding some basic error checking around the code, e.g. make sure m != None before setting l, just in case the code runs against a page that doesn't contain the desired pattern.

Comment: Thank you Paul , but how can I do this for multiple strings (same as above) it means if I have multiple 6 digit numbers , how can I pick them up ?

Comment: Edited my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks You for you replies Paul,Can I use:

for NOM in m:
 print m.group(NOM)

to print all of groups
it doesnt work for me

Comment: No, findall() doesn't return a Match object, just a list that you can iterate directly, e.g. `for NOM in m: print NOM`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a look-ahead and a look-behind for the checking:

```
m = re.search(r'(?<=>)\d{6}(?=<)', s)
l = m.group(0)
```

This regex will match to 6 digits that are preceded by a `>` and followed by a `<`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check for any whitespace (tabs, space, newlines) between the tags.  \s* means zero or more whitespace.

```
s='<td style="width:40px;">\n\n705214\t\n</td>'
m=re.search(r'>\s*(\d{6})\s*<',s)
m.groups()
('705214',)
```

Parsing HTML is a blast. Usually you treat the file as one long line, remove leading and trailing whitespace between the values contained inside the tags.  Maybe looking into a HTML table parsing module may help, especially if you need to parse several columns.

[stackoverflow answer using lxml etree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325216/parse-html-table-to-python-list/6325277#6325277)  
Also, htmp.parser was suggested.  Food for thought. 
(Still learning what modules python has to offer :) )