# Parsing a table with rowspan and colspan

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, html-table

I have a table that I need to parse, specifically it is a school schedule with 4 blocks of time, and 5 blocks of days for every week. I've attempted to parse it, but honestly have not gotten very far because I am stuck with how to deal with rowspan and colspan attributes, because they essentially mean there is a lack of data that I need to continue.

As an example of what I want to do, here's a table:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">#1</td>
    <td rowspan="4">#2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">#3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">#4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">#5</td>
    <td rowspan="2">#6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
</tr>
```

I want to take that table and convert it into this list:

```
[[1,1,2,3,4],
 [1,1,2,3,4],
 [1,1,2,5,6],
 [1,1,2,5,6]]
```

Right now I'm getting a flat list, similar to this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But in dictionary form, with information regarding how many columns and rows it spans, a description of it and what week it's in.

Obviously this needs to work for every possibility of rowspan/colspan, and for multiple weeks in the same table.

The html is not as clean as I've portrayed it, there are a lot of attributes I've left out, and the text is obviously not as clean cut as 1,2,3,4 but rather blocks of descriptive text. But if I could get this part resolved then it should be easy enough to incorporate into what I've already written.

I've been using lxml.html and Python to do this, but I'm open to using other modules if it provides an easier solution.

I hope someone can help me, because I really don't know what to do.

EDIT:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td rowspan="4">Thing</td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is causing me some problems, this is outputting

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'Thing', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

With the code provided by reclosedev, what do I need to change to adapt it so it outputs

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'Thing', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'Thing', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'Thing', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'Thing', ' ']
```

Instead?

EDIT2: Using reclosedev's new function, it's approaching a solution, but there are still cases where it fails to place cells correctly:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> DMAT Aud. 6 </td>
        <td rowspan="4"> Exam</td>
        <td rowspan="2"> DMAT Aud. 7</td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> CART Aud. 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> CART Aud. 4</td>
        <td rowspan="2"> OOP Aud. 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With this, the original table shows it as such:

```
[
[' ', ' DMAT Aud. 6 ', ' Exam', ' DMAT Aud. 7', ' '],
[' ', ' DMAT Aud. 6 ', ' Exam', ' DMAT Aud. 7', ' CART Aud. 4'],
[' ', ' CART Aud. 4' , ' Exam', ' OOP Aud. 7' , ' CART Aud. 4'],
[' ', ' CART Aud. 4' , ' Exam', ' OOP Aud. 7' , ' ']
]
```

But the new call outputs this:

```
[
[' ', ' DMAT Aud. 6 ', ' Exam', ' DMAT Aud. 7', ' '],
[' ', ' DMAT Aud. 6 ', ' Exam', ' DMAT Aud. 7', ' CART Aud. 4'],
[' ', ' CART Aud. 4' , ' Exam', ' CART Aud. 4', ' OOP Aud. 7'],
[' ', ' CART Aud. 4' , ' Exam', ' OOP Aud. 7' , ' ']
]
```

Comment: It would really help us if you could show us what code you are currently using and what output you are actually getting, instead of output that is similar to what you are getting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE** (removed previous function)

**UPDATE2** fixed and simplified.

My first function was wrong. Here's another one, it's working but needs tests:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import defaultdict


def table_to_list(table):
    dct = table_to_2d_dict(table)
    return list(iter_2d_dict(dct))


def table_to_2d_dict(table):
    result = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(unicode))
    for row_i, row in enumerate(table.xpath('./tr')):
        for col_i, col in enumerate(row.xpath('./td|./th')):
            colspan = int(col.get('colspan', 1))
            rowspan = int(col.get('rowspan', 1))
            col_data = col.text_content()
            while row_i in result and col_i in result[row_i]:
                col_i += 1
            for i in range(row_i, row_i + rowspan):
                for j in range(col_i, col_i + colspan):
                    result[i][j] = col_data
    return result


def iter_2d_dict(dct):
    for i, row in sorted(dct.items()):
        cols = []
        for j, col in sorted(row.items()):
            cols.append(col)
        yield cols


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import lxml.html
    from pprint import pprint

    doc = lxml.html.parse('tables.html')
    for table_el in doc.xpath('//table'):
        table = table_to_list(table_el)
        pprint(table)
```

**tables.html**:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td rowspan="4">Thing</td>
        <td>1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 </td>
        <td>2 </td>
        <td>2 </td>
        <td>2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 </td>
        <td>3 </td>
        <td>3 </td>
        <td>3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4 </td>
        <td>4 </td>
        <td>4 </td>
        <td>4 </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">#1</td>
    <td rowspan="4">#2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">#3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">#4</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">#5</td>
    <td rowspan="2">#6</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

Output:

```python
[['1 ', '1 ', '1 ', 'Thing', '1 '],
 ['2 ', '2 ', '2 ', 'Thing', '2 '],
 ['3 ', '3 ', '3 ', 'Thing', '3 '],
 ['4 ', '4 ', '4 ', 'Thing', '4 ']]
[['#1', '#1', '#2', '#3', '#4'],
 ['#1', '#1', '#2', '#3', '#4'],
 ['#1', '#1', '#2', '#5', '#6'],
 ['#1', '#1', '#2', '#5', '#6']]
```

Comment: It took some to get it to working on what I needed it to do, specifically I needed to split the whole table into smaller tables and delete some rows and columns inside those tables, but in the end it worked.

Thank you so much.

Comment: reclosedev: I edited my main post, with a problem on how to handle a specific case. I'd be grateful if you could answer it.

Comment: @Atheuz, see updated answer. First function really was wrong :(, but this one should work.

Comment: It does work now, I'm checking the results manually but everything seems to be right. Thanks for coming back and helping again, as I would have been stuck without you. Your new functions fit right into the adaptions I had made to it, it was just a matter of exchanging one call with another. Thank you so much.

Comment: There appears to be a case or two where this does not place the cells in the correct, position. I'll add an example to the OP.

Comment: that did it. It seems to me that this is a thing that libraries like BeautifulSoup or lxml should be able to do, because that is way over my head.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks - I found this snippet useful. Only change I needed was for supporting invalid non-numeric colspan / rowspan attributes.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: There is a bug in this answer (which is based on reclosedev solution)

See [How to parse table with rowspan and colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393253/how-to-parse-table-with-rowspan-and-colspan)

**Old**:

For those who want a Python 3 and BeautifulSoup solution,

```
def table_to_2d(table_tag):
    rows = table_tag("tr")
    cols = rows[0](["td", "th"])
    table = [[None] * len(cols) for _ in range(len(rows))]
    for row_i, row in enumerate(rows):
        for col_i, col in enumerate(row(["td", "th"])):
            insert(table, row_i, col_i, col)
    return table


def insert(table, row, col, element):
    if row >= len(table) or col >= len(table[row]):
        return
    if table[row][col] is None:
        value = element.get_text()
        table[row][col] = value
        if element.has_attr("colspan"):
            span = int(element["colspan"])
            for i in range(1, span):
                table[row][col+i] = value
        if element.has_attr("rowspan"):
            span = int(element["rowspan"])
            for i in range(1, span):
                table[row+i][col] = value
    else:
        insert(table, row, col + 1, element)
```

Usage:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<table><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>5</th></tr><tr><td rowspan="2">3</td><td colspan="2">4</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr></table>', 'html.parser')
print(table_to_2d(soup.table))
```

This is **NOT** optimized. I wrote this for my one-time script.

Comment: `if row+i < len(table): table[row+i][col] = value` need the condition in case the last rowspan is invalidly longer than the number of rows left in the table