# Expressive python library for parsing HTML tables

Tags: python, html-parsing, html-table

I need to parse html tables to do things like get all cells in a column above/below or left/right of a certain cell. Is there a python library that can do this easily?

Answer (score 2):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) - XML and HTML with Python - to parse a table. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6325277/889576) is a simple example of what you can do with a table (load & iterate through rows).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pyquery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery). It allows to make jquery queries on xml documents. A quick look at the [API](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/api.html) seemed that prevAll and nextAll can find the left/right cells. Think it will not be that difficult to get the above/below ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code convert all tables in page to lists.

```
import pandas as pd
url = r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
tables = pd.read_html(url) # Returns list of all tables on page
sp500_table = tables[0] # Select table of interest
```