# Python, Pandas : write content of DataFrame into text File

Tags: python, pandas, file-io

I have pandas DataFrame like this

```
        X    Y  Z    Value 
0      18   55  1      70   
1      18   55  2      67 
2      18   57  2      75     
3      18   58  1      35  
4      19   54  2      70
```

I want to write this data to a text file that looks like this:

```
18 55 1 70   
18 55 2 67 
18 57 2 75     
18 58 1 35  
19 54 2 70
```

I have tried something like

```
f = open(writePath, 'a')
f.writelines(['\n', str(data['X']), ' ', str(data['Y']), ' ', str(data['Z']), ' ', str(data['Value'])])
f.close()
```

It's not correct. How to do this?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can just use [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and access the np attribute `.values`:

```
np.savetxt(r'c:\data\np.txt', df.values, fmt='%d')
```

yields:

```
18 55 1 70
18 55 2 67
18 57 2 75
18 58 1 35
19 54 2 70
```

or [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv):

```
df.to_csv(r'c:\data\pandas.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

Note for `np.savetxt` you'd have to pass a filehandle that has been created with append mode.

Comment: Why is this answer getting so many more upvotes than @johndanger's?  His only uses df, so seems preferable to using np.

Comment: For those dealing with `str` values; pass `fmt=%s`.

Comment: What if I need to keep column names?

Comment: @ShaunHan Did you have any update to do it ? 
I've posted an open question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74521366/11167163)

Answer (score 88):

The native way to do this is to use `df.to_string()` :

```
with open(writePath, 'a') as f:
    dfAsString = df.to_string(header=False, index=False)
    f.write(dfAsString)
```

Will output the following

```
18 55 1 70   
18 55 2 67 
18 57 2 75     
18 58 1 35  
19 54 2 70
```

This method also lets you easily choose which columns to print with the `columns` attribute, lets you keep the column, index labels if you wish, and has other attributes for spacing ect.

Comment: Seems like this should be top answer, doesn't use any additional libraries than user requested (pandas).

Comment: @FredZimmerman I guess. `df.to_csv()` is usually better than this. And many people prefer working with np for speed reasons, they can make good use of `np.savetxt()`, which is still part of the question since it uses pandas for the Dataframe as a start.

Comment: df.to_csv() would not generalize well to a dataframe that contains strings, as the method will insert quotes everywhere. But np.savetxt() with fmt='%s' will handle strings very well.

Answer (score 37):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv), and setting both `index` and `header` to `False`:

```
In [97]: print df.to_csv(sep=' ', index=False, header=False)
18 55 1 70
18 55 2 67
18 57 2 75
18 58 1 35
19 54 2 70
```

`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` can write to a file directly, for more info you can refer to the docs linked above.

Comment: this will run into a lot of trouble when escaping needs to happen, it's not the solution to the general Pandas case!

Comment: I'm surprised by the amount of upvotes on this. Not something I'd recommend

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 care to elaborate? My answer here is of course not ideal as OP picked the better answer. It would be great if you provide more context, better still you provide an alternative solution -- so everyone can learn from your insight.

Comment: To `print(...)` isn't to store to a text file canonically; also your solution seems to use `Python 2`.

Answer (score 18):

Late to the party: Try this>

```
base_filename = 'Values.txt'
with open(os.path.join(WorkingFolder, base_filename),'w') as outfile:
    df.to_string(outfile)
#Neatly allocate all columns and rows to a .txt file
```

Comment: This doesn't give a tab delimited text file, seems to output a space delimited file. I like the elegance of this code, is there a way to make the output tab delimited?

Comment: @AHegde If you use tab delim then it would not have the beautiful formatting? Im just guessing as using space allows for neat alignment of rows/columns with different length.

Answer (score 13):

@AHegde - To get the tab delimited output use separator sep='\t'.

For df.to_csv:

```
df.to_csv(r'c:\data\pandas.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')
```

For np.savetxt:

```
np.savetxt(r'c:\data\np.txt', df.values, fmt='%d', delimiter='\t')
```

Answer (score 2):

I used a slightly modified version:

```
with open(file_name, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for rec_index, rec in df.iterrows():
        f.write(rec['<field>'] + '\n')
```

I had to write the contents of a dataframe field (that was delimited) as a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Way to get Excel data to text file in tab delimited form.
Need to use Pandas as well as xlrd.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import os

Path="C:\downloads"
wb = pd.ExcelFile(Path+"\\input.xlsx", engine=None)
sheet2 = pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name="Sheet1")
Excel_Filter=sheet2[sheet2['Name']=='Test']
Excel_Filter.to_excel("C:\downloads\\output.xlsx", index=None)
wb2=xlrd.open_workbook(Path+"\\output.xlsx")
df=wb2.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
x=df.nrows
y=df.ncols

for i in range(0,x):
    for j in range(0,y):
        A=str(df.cell_value(i,j))
        f=open(Path+"\\emails.txt", "a")
        f.write(A+"\t")
        f.close()
    f=open(Path+"\\emails.txt", "a")
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()
os.remove(Path+"\\output.xlsx")
print(Excel_Filter)
```

We need to first generate the xlsx file with filtered data and then convert the information into a text file.

Depending on requirements, we can use \n \t for loops and type of data we want in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Dataframe that is an output of [pandas compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html?highlight=compare#pandas.DataFrame.compare) method, such a dataframe looks like below when it is printed:

```
    grossRevenue          netRevenue               defaultCost
             self  other         self         other             self  other
2098        150.0  160.0          NaN           NaN              NaN    NaN
2110       1400.0  400.0          NaN           NaN              NaN    NaN
2127          NaN    NaN          NaN           NaN              0.0  909.0
2137          NaN    NaN     0.000000  8.900000e+01              NaN    NaN
2150          NaN    NaN     0.000000  8.888889e+07              NaN    NaN
2162          NaN    NaN  1815.000039  1.815000e+03              NaN    NaN
```

I was looking to persist the whole dataframe into a text file as its visible above. Using pandas's `to_csv` or numpy's `savetxt` does not achieve this goal. I used plain old `print` to log the same into a text file:

```
 with open('file1.txt', mode='w') as file_object:
            print(data_frame, file=file_object)
```