# Align output data using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to align and organized data on Output. I have an excel file which has 2 sheets - `Students`, `Anime`. I already extracted data on excel files but my problem now is the output. This is what i've tried

```
file = pd.read_excel("src/doc/x1/students.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
print(file)
```

Output:

```
{'Students':       Name        Major     Block
0     Alex     Business  20200525
1     Clay  Engineering  20200526
2  Justine      Science  20200527, 'Anime':      Anime Name             Author
0     One Piece       Eiichiro Oda
1        Naruto  Masashi Kishomoto
2  Dragon Balls     Akira Toriyama}
```

How do I remove the Brackets on each end and align data like this

```
    'Students':       Name        Major     Block
                0     Alex     Business  20200525
                1     Clay  Engineering  20200526
                2  Justine      Science  20200527 

    'Anime':        Anime Name          Author
             0     One Piece        Eiichiro Oda
             1     Naruto           Masashi Kishomoto
             2     Dragon Balls      Akira Toriyama
```

Comment: Your input data looks not aligned ? How does initial dataframe looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `file` is a dictionary where each key is the sheet's name and the value is the `Dataframe` from that sheet. you can use something like this and change the printing style to whatever you want:

```
for key, value in file.items():
    print(key + ":")
    print(value)
```

Comment: almost ok but i want to export this as text file. how do i combine the key and value on one text file if i do `print(value,file = open("mytext.txt", "w"))`

Comment: When writing or reading from file please use `with open(...)` and then instead of printing just write it to the file

Comment: visit this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428539/data-frame-to-file-txt-python/41428596) to find out how to write a `df` to a `.txt` file

Comment: I already output the Key and Value but I want to combine it on one text file. How can i do it

Comment: visit the link I attached in the previous comment. It shows  how to write a df into a `.txt` file. I am not sure if you can write all dataframes into one file together (if you can then great) *but* what you can do is write each dataframe into a temp `.txt` file, copy its content and write to the main `.txt` file from the temp one