# Converting to text file from dataframe doesnt separate lines

Tags: python, pandas, export, export-to-csv

I use export from pandas data frame in Jupyter:

```
        df_merged.to_csv(text_file, index=True, mode='a', sep=' ')
```

In Jupyter all looks nice:

[image]

But when I download it I see that the lines are not separated:

[image]

Please, dont you know where the issue might be?
Thanks!

RESULT: this helped for Windows:

```
        df_merged.to_csv(text_file, index=False, mode='a', sep='\t', line_terminator='\r\n')
```

Comment: which lines are not seperated?

Comment: which format is your text_file? Does `.txt`has line breakers? Try to export it as csv, then it should work

Comment: You can try `line_terminator='\n'` in the `to_csv` arguments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247198/python-pandas-write-content-of-dataframe-into-text-file

Comment: Hi, this helped:                df_merged.to_csv(text_file, index=False, mode='a', sep='\t', line_terminator='\r\n')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like:

1. you are on Windows
2. you are viewing the file in Notepad

Pandas will write out the csv file with newline `'\n'` only as the line separator.  Notepad will only break a line if it has carriage returns `'\r'`.

I would recommend using a different text editor such as Notepad++