# writing a dataframe to a txt file

Tags: python, pandas, text

I want to take each row in my pandas dataframe and print it out. Here's what I got so far. I want 3 decimal places to columns, x, y, z.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('2atoms.csv')
outF= open("firsttxt.txt", "w")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['index','x','y','z'])
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
for line in df:
    outF.write(data)
    outF.write("\n")
outF.close()
```

I thought that outF command would work but it is only for string...what else can be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Pandas : write content of DataFrame into text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247198/python-pandas-write-content-of-dataframe-into-text-file)

Comment: Do you want to print or export the data?

Comment: export the data to a txt file with 3 decimal points