# How to save a data frame and it's column to a text file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `DF` as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'B': [2]})
```

I'm trying to save it to a `Test.txt` file by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31247247/11167163), with:

```py
np.savetxt(r'Test.txt', DF, fmt='%s')
```

Which does save only `DF` values and not the column names:

```
1 2
```

How do I save it to have `Test.txt` with the following contents?

```
A B
1 2
```

Comment: What you're showing is a numPy array and not a dataframe. If youre actually using a pandas DataFrame somewhere, you use df.to_csv -> `https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html`

Comment: From the same answer you linked, change `header=True` in the Pandas solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same answer you linked, if you want to use Pandas, just change `header=True` like:

```py
DF.to_csv('Test.txt', header=True, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

If you want to use [`np.savetxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```py
np.savetxt(
    'Test.txt',
    DF.values,
    fmt='%s',
    header=' '.join(DF.columns),
    comments=''
)
```

Note that I changed the `comments` parameter to an empty string because the default is to add `#` in front of the header.