# Write array to .txt-file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, txt

In Python I need to write a list of numpy-arrays (see attached picture) to a txt.-file and then reuse that original list of arrays in a new python-file. How can I do that?

[image]

```py
read_files = open("read_files.txt","w+")

content = str(df)

read_files.write(content)
read_files.close()
```

Then in the new python-file I did:

```py
file = open("read_files.txt", "r")
content = file.read()
```

But when I want to slice the list of arrays in the new python-file I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Could you give the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: You can use `numpy.save` or `numpy.savetxt`

Comment: That's all @AndrewRyan

Comment: does it work with 3D array? @Corralien

Comment: If you want to reuse this data, don't use .txt files; use pickle for data serialization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Pandas : write content of DataFrame into text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247198/python-pandas-write-content-of-dataframe-into-text-file)

Comment: @yessir22 Python errors come with a stack trace above them that you'll want to include when asking folks about errors (they typically contain important information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) for 3D arrays:

```
arr = np.random.random((20, 10, 5))

np.save('arr', arr)  # extension .npy

arr2 = np.load('arr.npy')
```

Note: the file is not human readable.

Output:

```
>>> np.all(arr2 == arr)
True
```