# How to parse an HTML table with rowspans in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-table

**The problem**

I'm trying to parse an HTML table with rowspans in it, as in, I'm trying to parse my college schedule.

I'm running into the problem where if the last row contains a rowspan, the next row is missing a TD where the rowspan is now that TD that is missing.

I have no clue how to account for this and I hope to be able to parse this schedule.

**What I tried**

Pretty much everything I can think of.

**The result I get**

```
[
    {
        'blok_eind': 4,
        'blok_start': 3,
        'dag': 4, # Should be 5
        'leraar': 'DOODF000',
        'lokaal': 'ALK C212',
        'vak': 'PROJ-T',
    },
]
```

As you can see, there's a `vak` key with the value `PROJ-T` in the output snippet above, `dag` is `4` while it's supposed to be `5` (a.k.a Friday/Vrijdag), as seen here:

[image: Table]

**The result I want**

A Python dict() that looks like the one posted above, but with the right value

Where:

- `day`/`dag` is an int from 1~5 representing Monday~Friday
- `block_start`/`blok_start` is an int that represents when the course starts (Time block, left side of table)
- `block_end`/`blok_eind` is an int that represent in what block the course ends
- `classroom`/`lokaal` is the classroom's code the course is in
- `teacher`/`leraar` is the teacher's ID
- `course`/`vak` is the ID of the course

**Basic HTML Structure for above data**

```
<center>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <font>
                                    TEACHER-ID
                                </font>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <font>
                                    <b>
                                        CLASSROOM ID
                                    </b>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <font>
                                    COURSE ID
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

**The code**

*HTML*

```
<CENTER><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
<BR></font>
  <font size="6" face="Arial" color="#0000FF">
16AO4EIO1B
&nbsp;</font> <font size="4" face="Arial">
IO1B
</font>
  <BR>
  <TABLE border="3" rules="all" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <TR>
      <TD align="center">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#000000">
Maandag 29-08
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
Dinsdag 30-08
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
Woensdag 31-08
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
Donderdag 01-09
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
Vrijdag 02-09
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>1</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
8:30
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
9:20
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=4 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
BLEEJ002
</font> </TD>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
<B>ALK B021</B>
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
WEBD
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>2</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
9:20
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
10:10
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=4 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
BLEEJ002
</font> </TD>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
<B>ALK B021B</B>
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
WEBD
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>3</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
10:25
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
11:15
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=4 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
DOODF000
</font> </TD>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
<B>ALK C212</B>
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
PROJ-T
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>4</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
11:15
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
12:05
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=4 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
BLEEJ002
</font> </TD>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
<B>ALK B021B</B>
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
MENT
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>5</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
12:05
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
12:55
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>6</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
12:55
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
13:45
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=4 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
JONGJ003
</font> </TD>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
<B>ALK B008</B>
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
BURG
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>7</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
13:45
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
14:35
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=4 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
FLUIP000
</font> </TD>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
<B>ALK B004</B>
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
ICT algemeen  Prakti
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>8</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
14:50
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
15:40
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=4 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
KOOLE000
</font> </TD>
            <TD width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
<B>ALK B008</B>
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD colspan="2" width="50%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
NED
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>9</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
15:40
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
16:30
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" rowspan="2" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial">
<B>10</B>
</font> </TD>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
16:30
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">
17:20
</font> </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
      <TD colspan=12 rowspan=2 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD></TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <TABLE cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <TR>
      <TD valign=bottom> <font size="4" face="Arial" color="#0000FF"></TR></TABLE><font size="3" face="Arial">
Periode1   29-08-2016 (35) - 04-09-2016 (35)   G r u b e r  &amp;  P e t t e r s   S o f t w a r e
</font></CENTER>
```

*Python*

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://rooster.horizoncollege.nl/rstr/ECO/AMR/400-ECO/Roosters/36"
                 "/c/c00025.htm")
daytable = {
    1: "Maandag",
    2: "Dinsdag",
    3: "Woensdag",
    4: "Donderdag",
    5: "Vrijdag"
}
timetable = {
    1: ("8:30", "9:20"),
    2: ("9:20", "10:10"),
    3: ("10:25", "11:15"),
    4: ("11:15", "12:05"),
    5: ("12:05", "12:55"),
    6: ("12:55", "13:45"),
    7: ("13:45", "14:35"),
    8: ("14:50", "15:40"),
    9: ("15:40", "16:30"),
    10: ("16:30", "17:20"),
}

page = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

roster = []
big_rows = 2
last_row_big = False
# There are 10 blocks, each made up out of 2 TR's, run through them
for block_count in range(2, 22, 2):
    # There are 5 days, first column is not data we want
    for day in range(2, 7):
        dayroster = {
            "dag": 0,
            "blok_start": 0,
            "blok_eind": 0,
            "lokaal": "",
            "leraar": "",
            "vak": ""
        }
        # This selector provides the classroom
        table_bold = page.select(
            "html > body > center > table > tr:nth-of-type(" + str(block_count) + ") > td:nth-of-type(" + str(
                day) + ") > table > tr > td > font > b")

        # This selector provides the teacher's code and the course ID
        table = page.select(
            "html > body > center > table > tr:nth-of-type(" + str(block_count) + ") > td:nth-of-type(" + str(
                day) + ") > table > tr > td > font")

        # This gets the rowspan on the current row and column
        rowspan = page.select(
            "html > body > center > table > tr:nth-of-type(" + str(block_count) + ") > td:nth-of-type(" + str(
                day) + ")")

        try:
            if table or table_bold and rowspan[0].attrs.get("rowspan") == "4":
                last_row_big = True
                # Setting end of class
                dayroster["blok_eind"] = (block_count // 2) + 1
            else:
                last_row_big = False
                # Setting end of class
                dayroster["blok_eind"] = (block_count // 2)
        except IndexError:
            pass

        if table_bold:
            x = table_bold[0]
            # Classroom ID
            dayroster["lokaal"] = x.contents[0]

        if table:
            iter = 0
            for x in table:
                content = x.contents[0].lstrip("\r\n").rstrip("\r\n")
                # Cell has data
                if content != "":
                    # Set start of class
                    dayroster["blok_start"] = block_count // 2
                    # Set day of class
                    dayroster["dag"] = day - 1
                    if iter == 0:
                        # Teacher ID
                        dayroster["leraar"] = content
                    elif iter == 1:
                        # Course ID
                        dayroster["vak"] = content
                    iter += 1

        if table or table_bold:
            # Store the data
            roster.append(dayroster)

# Remove duplicates
seen = set()
new_l = []
for d in roster:
    t = tuple(d.items())
    if t not in seen:
        seen.add(t)
        new_l.append(d)
pprint(new_l)
```

Comment: Please include 1) your Python code, 2) a minimal amount of HTML necessary to reproduce the problem, 3) your expected output, and 4) what you're getting instead in the question itself, rather than on an external website.

Comment: @Ryan done, i hope this is better.

Comment: _I'm running into the problem where if the last row contains a rowspan, the next row is missing a TD where the rowspan is now that TD that is missing._  Are you saying that the `<td>` is actually missing from the html, or are you saying your code _thinks_ it's missing when it actually isn't?

Comment: @JohnGordon the `<td>` is indeed missing from the html as the `rowspan` attribute in the previous row makes it span across multiple rows, in the html that results in the need for one less `<td>` in the next row, otherwise you'd have 5 columns in the previous row, and 6 columns in the next row (5x `<td>` and 1x the `<td>` from the previous row because it had the `rowspan` attribute)

Comment: requests returns a 404 error page

Comment: the site url gives a 404

Comment: The week number should be changed in the url, it's 35 but should be 36.

Comment: And now the class changed, c00019.htm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to track the rowspans on previous rows, one per column.

You could do this simply by copying the integer value of a rowspan into a dictionary, and subsequent rows decrement the rowspan value until it drops to `1` (or we could store the integer value minus 1 and drop to `0` for ease of coding). Then you can adjust subsequent table counts based on preceding rowspans.

Your table complicates this a little by using a default span of size 2, incrementing in steps of two, but that can easily be brought back to manageable numbers by dividing by 2.

Rather than use massive CSS selectors, select just the table rows and we'll iterate over those:

```
roster = []
rowspans = {}  # track rowspanning cells
# every second row in the table
rows = page.select('html > body > center > table > tr')[1:21:2]
for block, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    # take direct child td cells, but skip the first cell:
    daycells = row.select('> td')[1:]
    rowspan_offset = 0
    for daynum, daycell in enumerate(daycells, 1):
        # rowspan handling; if there is a rowspan here, adjust to find correct position
        daynum += rowspan_offset
        while rowspans.get(daynum, 0):
            rowspan_offset += 1
            rowspans[daynum] -= 1
            daynum += 1
        # now we have a correct day number for this cell, adjusted for
        # rowspanning cells.
        # update the rowspan accounting for this cell
        rowspan = (int(daycell.get('rowspan', 2)) // 2) - 1
        if rowspan:
            rowspans[daynum] = rowspan

        texts = daycell.select("table > tr > td > font")
        if texts:
            # class info found
            teacher, classroom, course = (c.get_text(strip=True) for c in texts)
            roster.append({
                'blok_start': block,
                'blok_eind': block + rowspan,
                'dag': daynum,
                'leraar': teacher,
                'lokaal': classroom,
                'vak': course
            })

    # days that were skipped at the end due to a rowspan
    while daynum < 5:
        daynum += 1
        if rowspans.get(daynum, 0):
            rowspans[daynum] -= 1
```

This produces correct output:

```
[{'blok_eind': 2,
  'blok_start': 1,
  'dag': 5,
  'leraar': u'BLEEJ002',
  'lokaal': u'ALK B021',
  'vak': u'WEBD'},
 {'blok_eind': 3,
  'blok_start': 2,
  'dag': 3,
  'leraar': u'BLEEJ002',
  'lokaal': u'ALK B021B',
  'vak': u'WEBD'},
 {'blok_eind': 4,
  'blok_start': 3,
  'dag': 5,
  'leraar': u'DOODF000',
  'lokaal': u'ALK C212',
  'vak': u'PROJ-T'},
 {'blok_eind': 5,
  'blok_start': 4,
  'dag': 3,
  'leraar': u'BLEEJ002',
  'lokaal': u'ALK B021B',
  'vak': u'MENT'},
 {'blok_eind': 7,
  'blok_start': 6,
  'dag': 5,
  'leraar': u'JONGJ003',
  'lokaal': u'ALK B008',
  'vak': u'BURG'},
 {'blok_eind': 8,
  'blok_start': 7,
  'dag': 3,
  'leraar': u'FLUIP000',
  'lokaal': u'ALK B004',
  'vak': u'ICT algemeen  Prakti'},
 {'blok_eind': 9,
  'blok_start': 8,
  'dag': 5,
  'leraar': u'KOOLE000',
  'lokaal': u'ALK B008',
  'vak': u'NED'}]
```

Moreover, this code will continue to work even if courses span *more than 2 blocks*, or just one block; any rowspan size is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is better to use bs4 builtin function like "**findAll**" to parse your table.

You may use the following code :

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://rooster.horizoncollege.nl/rstr/ECO/AMR/400-ECO/Roosters/36"
                 "/c/c00025.htm")

content=r.content
page = BeautifulSoup(content, "html")
table=page.find('table')
trs=table.findAll("tr", {},recursive=False)
tr_count=0
trs.pop(0)
final_table={}

for tr in trs:
    tds=tr.findAll("td", {},recursive=False)
    if tds:
        td_count=0
        tds.pop(0)
        for td in tds:
            if td.has_attr('rowspan'):                              
                final_table[str(tr_count)+"-"+str(td_count)]=td.text.strip()
                if int(td.attrs['rowspan'])==4:
                    final_table[str(tr_count+1)+"-"+str(td_count)]=td.text.strip()
                if final_table.has_key(str(tr_count)+"-"+str(td_count+1)):
                    td_count=td_count+1         
            td_count=td_count+1
        tr_count=tr_count+1

roster=[]
for i in range(0,10): #iterate over time
    for j in range(0,5): #iterate over day
        item=final_table[str(i)+"-"+str(j)]
        if len(item)!=0:    
            block_eind=i+1          

            try:
                if final_table[str(i+1)+"-"+str(j)]==final_table[str(i)+"-"+str(j)]:
                        block_eind=i+2
            except:
                pass

            try:
                lokaal=item.split('\r\n \n\n')[0]
                leraar=item.split('\r\n \n\n')[1].split('\n \n\r\n')[0]
                vak=item.split('\n \n\r\n')[1]
            except:
                lokaal=leraar=vak="---"

            dayroster = {
                "dag": j+1,
                "blok_start": i+1,
                "blok_eind": block_eind,
                "lokaal": lokaal,
                "leraar": leraar,
                "vak": vak
            }


            dayroster_double = {
                "dag": j+1,
                "blok_start": i,
                "blok_eind": block_eind,
                "lokaal": lokaal,
                "leraar": leraar,
                "vak": vak
            }

            #use to prevent double dict for same event
            if dayroster_double not in roster:
                roster.append(dayroster)

print (roster)
```

Comment: You'd use `find_all`; `findAll` is only there to support BeautifulSoup 3 code and is deprecated in favour of the PEP8 compliant name.

Comment: You are right, thank you. The change was made in my code. It is clear that your version is absolutely better than mine. Regards

Comment: Next nit: `==True` is never needed in `if` statements; leave testing if the expression produced a true result to `if` itself. `if td.has_attr('rowspan'):` works just as well as `if td.has_attr('rowspan')==True:` but is cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Martijn, I know that and I am agree with you. I change code according to this.